# How to make visual representation of WebStorm and Eclipse editor same

Tags: eclipse, fonts, editor, webstorm, codehighlighter

I am trying to make my WebStorm and Eclipse visual representation of code as same.

I had made majority of stuff in WebStorm as same Eclipse with one last thing.

If we observe the keyword `function` is bold in Eclipse while in WebStorm it it not.

***How to tell WebStorm to show keywords as bold as it shows in Eclipse?***

I am using `Obsidian` with font as `Consolas`
WebStorm - 10
Eclipse - Kepller

[image]

Comment: `function` is a keyword -- make sure that `JavaScript | Keyword` has `bold` option set. If nothing -- post screenshot of that settings page.

Comment: @LazyOne webstorm = awesomeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function` is a keyword. Therefore make sure that `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Keyword` has bold option set.